# How to set the background image of a TableView added with a Navigation Controller - Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I want to set the background image for a `TableView` I got by adding a navigation controller to my scene.

I tried using a `UIImageView` but can't find where to put it in the hierarchy.

Is it possible to add the `UIImageView` via Storyboard in this case?

thanks in advance

if I put an `UIImage` in hierarchy, I got this
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- create a custom class for your navigation controller
- add this code into the viewDidLoad of that controller

  ```
  var imageView = UIImageView(frame: self.view.frame)
  var image = UIImage(named: "BGimage")!
  imageView.image = image
  self.view.addSubview(imageView)
  self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)
  ```
- change the class in your storyboard for that view controller to the custom controller
- for your table view and it's cells make sure the backgroundColor is set to clearColor:

  myTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

in code or via Interfacebuilder.

all set and done

Comment: Hard to see how I could help you from here, use the code version, it works ;)

Comment: I removed my comments a bit to clean up this question/answer please do this also (it's handier for others. I'll add the solution to my answer but here is the zip file anyway : https://www.dropbox.com/s/mbfndf3eb3f8jyv/NavigationControllerTableView-background.zip?dl=0

Comment: I'm clearing up my comments too, your solution is what I was looking for! last point, will it be autolayouting? if yes how?. AnyWay, Thank you so much! (I'll clear this comment too in few hours)

Comment: it will be using standard constraints, which should be good enough. If not add constraints in code in the Navigation controller

Comment: yes, just like then, if you have any other questions, please use my email provided in the template so we won't clutter comments. If it's relevant I'll add it to the answer

Comment: I have a problem related to your solution, maybe you can help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145818/wrong-order-in-navigation-bar-and-table-view