# Wrong order in navigation bar and table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar

from a Home VC, embedded in a storyboard:
I tap on the left button, performing a segue. 
This segue will lead me to a navigation controller with its own tableview (the one that comes with the object). I simply want a black navigation bar, but it seems that navigation bar is before the view and the view, i before the tableView.

in storyboard I set:
the navigation bar to "opaque black navigation bar"
in table view's attributes inspector I set view's background to red (is a test)

**check the last image for update**

my storyboard:

[image]

the problem in the storyboard:

[image]

but what I obtain is a sort of sovrapposition, like this.

[image]

**UPADATE (new problem navigation bar black, status bar transparent, and can't hide it from storyboard):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

Comment: I added in my `ProvaTableViewController` `viewDidLoad` this: `        `self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = false`
` but it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard for the viewController check if the "Adjust Scroll View Insets" property is checked unser "View Contoller" layout[image]

Comment: your solution worked fine on some VC, but now I have the problem you can see on the update. where your solution failed, I changed the color of the navigation bar in the storyboard but got that result. Can you help me?

Comment: the navigation bar color is gray ? Is that the issue ?

Comment: navigation bar is black, the status bar is transparent